# Media screen css not rendering images correctly

Tags: html, css, image, screen, media

I have a blog page [KW-Masterointi](http://www.kw-masterointi.fi/blog.html) where I also add images between text. For some reason, if I enter the image dimensions in HTML, the image is not showing correctly in mobile view. I have set the image max with to 100% in my css, but the images show correct only when I remowe the image dimensions from the HTML code.

Currently I have all images except one without dimensions. The one image with dimensions is FGx.jpg on row 299. When I look at the page in mobile view, this image looks funny. All the others render correctly.

Something is overriding the {max with 100%} in my css, but I haven't been able to figure out what it is.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks
Kim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use !important at the end of styles in your CSS to override inline-styling.

Ex.)

```
.container { 
          width: 100% !important;
          height: auto;
     }
```

The height: auto; will ensure your images don't get distorted when resizing to smaller screens.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are explicitly defining the width and height in pixel of image in img tag, so that's why no other style is working on that element.
By defining the explicit width and height, responsiveness will not working on your image.